# Logging file system actions for Hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I have problem at hand, that requires me to monitor as set of files that are being accessed. The files can both be accessed from the Hadoop file system and the file system on the Linux machine.

I need to constantly monitor and integrate logs from both the file-systems, for a group of specific few files.

Any Ideas on how this can be done ?

Comment: well, yes. We have been using inotify to monitor certain folders inside the linux machine. I wanted to extend the functionality to HDFS,

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Apache Hadoop 2.6.0 (or for Cloudera CDH users, 5.2.0 onwards), HDFS has added inotify-like features. The [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6634) for this carries [a design document](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12663753/inotify-design.4.pdf) that details the form of implementation HDFS supports for such a need.

A test case from the same implementation further illustrates how to make use of the feature: [TestDFSInotifyEventInputStream](https://github.com/cloudera/hadoop-common/blob/cdh5.4.5-release/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/TestDFSInotifyEventInputStream.java#L455-L477)

Remember also that by default the access time granularity (and thereby tracking) for HDFS is very low given its WORM performance semantics. You may want to reduce the value at the NameNode configuration, for the property `dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision`, from its default of 1 hour (in ms).